# How to take a color screenshot using Google Earth API?

Tags: vba, google-earth

I am using Google Earth API in Excel VBA. The screenshots are coming in black and white instead of color. Please suggest me where I am doing wrong?

```
Dim ge As earthlib.ApplicationGE

Set ge = New ApplicationGE

Dim kmlString As Variant

kmlString = "C:\temp\test.kmz"

ge.OpenKmlFile (kmlString, 1)

Dim tPlace As earthlib.FeatureGE

Set tPlace = ge.GetTemporaryPlaces

Dim fldrPath As String, jpgName as String

fldrPath = "C:\temp\"

jpgName = fldrPath & "outJpg1.JPG"

ge.SaveScreenShot (jpgName, 100)
```

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't nearly enough information here for anyone to assist you. You might consider posting the code you are using to call the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment I found [in this documentation](http://codeassemble.googlecode.com/svn/uCam/trunk/GoogleEarthDemo/earth.idl) suggests that this is by design. I haven't found anything that suggests what to do instead, though.

> ```
> /// \brief Takes low quality black and white screen shot
> /// of the current camera view.
> ///
> /// This image is not meant to  be used for rapid capture and degrades
> /// in quality if used frequently.
> ///
> /// \param fileName Full path JPG filename of output screen shot.
> /// \param quality Quality factor of output image. Lowest quality is
> /// \c 0 and highest quality is \c 100. Input quality is always clamped
> /// to (\c 0, \c 100) inclusive.
> ///
> /// \retval S_OK Successfully saved screen shot.
> /// \retval (other) Appropriate error code.
> [id(5), helpstring("method SaveScreenShot")]
> HRESULT SaveScreenShot([in] BSTR fileName, [in] long quality);
> ```

Comment: Thanks Akash, it means we can't capture color images using code. Correct?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I achieved it by using VBA application.sendkey method.